Trigger jenkins when changes are pushed to a specific folder
I have two different services in the same Github repositories and each one of these services has his own Jenkinsfile
repository/service-a/Jenkinsfile and
repository/service-b/Jenkinsfile
Every commit to GitHub repository is building both service-a and service-b.
What I want to achieve is only the impacted project should get rebuilt.
I looked at changeset and I came up with this conditions
service-a/Jenkinsfile :
stage('something') { when {  beforeAgent true not {  changeset "service-b/**"  } anyOf { changeset "service-a/**" } } }
I've tested this for service-a and the build for service-b gets skipped due to the when condition.
Is there anyway I prevent Jenkins from even triggering a skipped build.
Whenever I commit something to repository/service-a/ only the build for that service should be triggered.
